# How to permanently set the default gateway to a particular IP address?

Tags: router, internet, static-routes

I get a default gateway of 192.168.178.2 whenever I connect to my router, but I want 192.168.178.1.

Every time I connect to the Wi-Fi I have to delete and then re-add the default gateway. How can I solve this problem permanently?

----edit---
The router's IP address is 192.168.178.2 but for some reason I need the gateway to be 192.168.178.1 for the internet to work.

----edit---
My router at 192.168.178.2 has a static routes page where I can add new static IP routes. Can I use this? If it helps, my router is a FRITZ!Box 7710. I can't seem to find its default gateway setting.

Comment: Have you tried setting a static IP address, in there you'll have to set a gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, Yes. You will need to change the settings for the DHCP scope on the device that is giving out the IP addresses via DHCP.

Usually when you are setting up the scope initially everyone tends to leave this default, however. Sounds like you are using your Wi-Fi router to dish out addresses, before going through your modem.

Try this:

1. Log into your Wi-Fi router and add a default gateway setting there. (The most common places to find this in the UI would be under "basic setup" or "LAN settings".)

   or
2. Add a static route to your PC (not recommended)

Side Note: Your gateway address will always be your internet modem's IP address in your network.

Answer (score 1):

The router's DHCP service is misconfigured and giving you the wrong gateway. I presume the router is .1? It should be giving out its own IP address as the gateway.

Comment: not necessarily. It is possible to set up a small network so that a wifi router is not the gateway. For example, if you also have a separate cable modem for your internet access and a separate switch for a larger wired network, your router may only hand out addresses for a portion of your network's subnet, and the modem should be the default gateway (though personally in this situation I wouldn't use the router's dhcp service at all).